# How to implement encryption (3des) in flutter/darts

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I implement 3des encryption in Dart..

I download this library (https://pub.dev/packages/tripledes) However, I am not able to add the require values.. Example , how do you pass the iv value..

Here is my JS code (using crypto.js) that I need to convert to dart

```
  {
     key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
     iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(ivKey);
     var options = {
       mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
       padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
       iv: iv
     };
     var encrypted = CryptoJS.TripleDES.encrypt(token, key,  options);

    }
```

In Dart this is what I have so far

```
static String getEncrypt() {
    String key = HR_KEY;
    String id = "test";
    String message = id  + getUtcDate();
    var blockCipher = new BlockCipher(new TripleDESEngine(), key);
    var ciphertext = blockCipher.encodeB64(message);
    return ciphertext;
  }
```

Using the above code , how do I pass the iv, mode, padding etc

Thanks

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Nope.. I implement it in node/backend and then call it from my app..

Answer (score 1):

Do not use 3DES. It is not because was encrypted that it is secure!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When writing an answer, you may want to explain why you think your answer is correct, as it may be the case it is not targeting exactly the same problem and the explanation may help to see why

Comment: 3des only encrypts an 8-byte array in the usual way. The first position is the value you want to encrypt and the rest of the other 7 positions are random values. The answer below further explains how the technology works. This is not safe, it is just a bad taste.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation my client is using `ECB` mode and `DES.IV_ZEROS`

And I am using `dart_des` package and I achieved the solution something near your problem whit this code:

```
  String key = apiObject.key;
  Uint8List data = convert.base64Decode(key);

  DES3 desECB = DES3(key: data, mode: DESMode.ECB, iv: DES.IV_ZEROS);

  String cypher = "cypher text";
  List<int> bytes = convert.utf8.encode(cypher);
  bytes = [bytes[0], 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0]; // this is the secret
  // create a 8 positions byte array, and the first one is the only one that you update
  //and after this you encrypt the byte key with TripleDes
  List<int> encryptedChyper = desECB.encrypt(bytes);

  String value = convert.base64Encode(encryptedChyper);
```